# how to use dbt external_table package to add partition in spectrum

Tags: amazon-s3, dbt, external-tables

when I wanna use external_table to read S3 file spectrum and add partition at the same time I have such problem:

```
08:19:05  Postgres adapter: Rolling back transaction.
08:19:05  On macro_stage_external_sources: ROLLBACK
08:19:05  On macro_stage_external_sources: Close
uncaught python exception
'dict' object has no attribute 'resource_type'
```

here is the yml that I create

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: NAME
    schema: schema.NAME
    description: External schema from Amazon S3. Data catalog stored on AWS Glue.
    loader: s3
    tables:
      - name: TABLE_NAME
        description: External table from Amazon S3.
        external:
          location: "s3://S3_file_path/dt={{var('date', modules.datetime.date.today())}}" ## Remove the last "/" from s3 path
          partitions:
            - name: partition_date
              data_type: date
              vals:
                macro: dbt.dates_in_range
                args:
                  start_date_str: '2023-03-01'
                  end_date_str: '{{modules.datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}'
                  in_fmt: "%Y-%m-%d"
                  out_fmt: "%Y-%m-%d"
              path_macro: dbt_external_tables.value_only
        columns:
          - name: 'col_1'
            data_type: varchar(255)
          - name: 'col_2'
            data_type: varchar(255)
            description: 'col_2'
```

what I want to do is that
use redshift spectrum to read S3 parquet file day by day (where the file location format is s3://S3_file_path/dt=2023-03-01) and add that day's date as partition to this parquet file.

thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't precisely what you want, but my solution was to predefine the partitions by setting `end_date_str` to some date comfortably in the future, *e.g.* 5 years out. It's inelegant but works.